# node.js websocket server to html

Tags: node.js, websocket

I was wondering if you could help me with a conundrum. I'm new to node.js and would appreciate some help.

I have a simple html (client) page using jquery and socket.io.js a external server. the client sends events to a node.js app used as a websocket server, and this works well and as expected.

However I am clueless on how to do write the incomming events to something more useful than the console.log in the node.js app.

At the moment it could not be simpler.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);

io.set('log level',1);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {  
    socket.on('clientevent', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
});
```

I want to be able to write events from the client.html to some piece of html (DOM) from the node.js app. I want to do this with something like jquery's $('#event').append(message), and also be able to talk to the node.js server trough something like $('#someid').click...

Or am I going about this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic example is perfect. [Socket.io example with Jquery and DOM manipulation](https://gist.github.com/2814934) gives you a more elaborate example using Jquery and DOM manipulation. You'll have to upload client.html to a web-server, run app.js from node and then access client.html.

Socket.io listens on port 8000 and the client has already been configured to access it at that port. Specifically refer the code for [DOM manipulation](https://gist.github.com/2814934#L44) using Jquery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm a bit confused. Perhaps I'm being daft. Im able to do the client.html -> server.js at this point. 

The problem I have is that I want to do:

client.html(on apache)->(internet)->server.js->clientreplica.html

Where the client.html is on a regular server And the clientreplica.html is on the same server as node.js. Basically I want to write the events I get from a client on the "internet" to dynamic html. The server.js is basically a relay. Does it make any sence?

Comment: Oh, hold on on. I just noticed the broadcast part of the example. Does this mean that there can be multiple clients to the same server.js app?

Comment: Socket.io allows you to emit and receive custom events. broadcast as you see in this example is a specific use case of emit. Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else except the socket that starts it.

Comment: With Socket.io you could have multiple clients each emitting/listening to it's own set of events bound by a central server. So you could have

client1.html - listening to event1, event3 and emitting event6, event 7.
cleint2.html - listening to event2, event3 and emitting event5, event 7.

Moreover client1.html and client2.html need not be on the same server as the socket.io server.

server.js (the socket.io server) - will listen to event5, event6 and event7 and emit event1, event2 and event3.

Comment: I knew it was my noodle! Thank you almypal, a IRL Beer is always awaiting you in the Stockholm area, Sweden.